# Как во Flask лучше передать список из скрипта в html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Изучаю python и столкнулся с проблемой передачи списка из запущенного во flask скрипта обратно в html.
Из route запускаю скрипт freq.py который генерирует список.

freq.py

```
import re
import operator
from pprint import pprint
import requests


def get_text(link4word, words_or_phrases):
    r = requests.get(link4word)
    document_text = r.text
    text_string = document_text.lower()
    words_or_phrases_check(words_or_phrases, text_string)


def words_or_phrases_check(words_or_phrases, text_string):
    if words_or_phrases == 'word':
        match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[а-я]{4,15}\b', text_string)
    else:
        match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[а-я]{3,15}\b \b[а-я]{1,3}\b \b[а-я]{3,15}\b', text_string)  # словосочетание
    frequency = {}
    for word in match_pattern:
        count = frequency.get(word, 0)
        frequency[word] = count + 1

    frequency_list = frequency.keys()

    data = {}

    for words in frequency_list:
        # data = {words: frequency[words]}
        data[words] = frequency[words]

    seo_words = sorted(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        #seo_words2.append(b)
    return seo_words
```

Если напечатать seo_words, выводится список в терминале.

import freq

```
@app.route('/search_words', methods=['POST'])
def search_words(): 
    b = freq.get_text()
    return render_template('seo.html', seo_words=b)


@app.route('/seo')
def seo():
    return render_template('seo.html')
```

Значения списка я пытаюсь вернуть в html из которого и был запущен скрипт.

seo.html

```
<form name="f2" method="post" action="/search_words">
    ...
    <button type="submit" >Искать</button>
</form>

<div>{{ seo_words }}</div>
```

Но seo_words выводит None

Что делаю не правильно?
Список не пустой. Если вывести на печать через print, то список выводится в терминале. Пробовал и вывод терминала в html ни чего не выходит. Две недели пробить не могу.

Возможно такие вещи проще делать через базу данных, но это пока не проходили) 
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно вывести?

Comment: Цикл в шаблоне напишите

Comment: На цикл ругается TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Возможно код скрипта что-то прояснит. Добавлю в первый пост код freq.py

Comment: В одном обработчике у вас есть `seo_words`: `return render_template('seo.html', seo_words=b)`, а в другом нет `return render_template('seo.html')`

Comment: Если я пишу seo_words=b во втором обработчике, ошибка, что b пустая. Если я в обработчике объявляю b списком, то объявленный список выводится в шаблоне,  а не переданный.

Comment: Решил вопрос через запись и чтение базы данных или через файл. И в django)